# Как в Android TabLayout поместить ленту новостей?

Tags: android

Добрый вечер, меня интересует следующий вопрос: как поместить в табовое меню ленту новостей? 
Есть первый фрагмент:

```
package com.learn2crack.loginregistration.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.learn2crack.loginregistration.R;



public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    System.out.println("любой текст");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вместо текста ONE должна быть лента

Есть какие нибудь примеры добавление ленты или чего нибудь другого в меню? Спасибо большое, буду рад любым ответам!

Answer (score 3):

Отображение списка данных никак не связано с наличием/отсутствием табов.

Вам надо:

1. добавить RecyclerView в разметку.
2. Получить/создать список с данными
3. Создать адаптер для RecyclerView
4. Отобразить список данных через адаптер в RecyclerView.